# Passively get new access token after access token expires

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

I am working on a simple Facebook App that will allow me to post from my client's website to my client's Facebook Fan Page.

Right now I set the access token with `$facebook->setAccessToken( EXTENDED_ACCESS_TOKEN_IN_DB );` after creating my application instance with the PHP SDK.  I am using the 60 day long-lived extended access tokens so the client **does not** have to login to Facebook each time they want to post to the Fan Page.

At some point, the access token will become invalid for any number of reasons.

Under ideal circumstances this would be once every 60 days.  At the same time it would be nice if we could continue to publish to the Fan Page from the website through the app until the day arrives that the user de-authorizes the app.

Is there anyway to get a new access token once it has expired without asking the user to login to Facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway to get a new access token once it has expired without asking the user to login to Facebook?

No. That’s the whole point of deprecating offline_access – that apps can’t go on “forever” doing stuff in the user’s name.

Maybe you want to get a page access token instead of a user access token? The former ones don’t have a default expiry date.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  I do have a page access token.  From what I understand that page access token is tied to the user access token.  So wouldn't they both expire after 60 days (or at some other point) at the same time?

Comment: Nope, that’s only for page access tokens you acquired using a short-lived user access token – get it with a long-lived on, and it won’t expire by default. See https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Okay.  So if my page access token doesn't expire by default.  Will I still have to go "through the user" to post to the page they manage?  By "through the user" I mean, using a valid user access token for them.